# big.mark = "," doesn't work with kable function in Rmarkdown when transposing the data frame

Tags: r, latex, knitr, transpose, kable

I have a data frame with one row and many columns, and I want to present it with the kable function in Rmarkdown (PDF output). For presenting it in a better way I used the "transpose" function and generated a new data frame. The problem is when I'm using: big.mark = "," , it doesn't work on the transposed data frame, although it works when I'm using the original data frame.
I'm attaching here an example to this problem by code I wrote to demonstrate that problem:

````
```{r warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, message=FALSE, echo = FALSE, results = 
'hide'}
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, message=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
df <- data.frame(x=1000, y=scales::percent(0.34), z=500000)
kable(df, format = "latex", caption = "big.mark problem", booktabs=TRUE, 
format.args = list(big.mark = ","))
```

```{r warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, message=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
df_transpose <- t(data.frame(x=1000, y=scales::percent(0.34), z=500000))
kable(df_transpose, format = "latex", caption = "big.mark problem", 
booktabs=TRUE, format.args = list(big.mark = ","))
```

```{r warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, message=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
df_transpose_df <- as.data.frame(t(data.frame(x=1000, 
y=scales::percent(0.34), z=500000)))
kable(df_transpose_df, format = "latex", caption = "big.mark problem", 
booktabs=TRUE, format.args = list(big.mark = ","))
```

```{r warning = FALSE, error = FALSE, message=FALSE, echo = FALSE}
df_transpose_tibble <- as.tibble(t(data.frame(x=1000, 
y=scales::percent(0.34), z=500000)))
kable(df_transpose_tibble, format = "latex", caption = "big.mark problem", 
booktabs=TRUE, format.args = list(big.mark = ","))
```
````

The first table display the first number as: 1,000.
and the other tables display them as: 1000.
I want that all will be looked like the first one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've got data types issues here. Forgetting about the `kable` stuff for a minute, go through and investigate the class and structure of each object you've created.

First off is the fact that `scales::percent` formats a number and returns a string.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

scales::percent(0.34)
#> [1] "34.0%"
class(scales::percent(0.34))
#> [1] "character"
```

Because `data.frame` has a default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, that string you've created for `y` is now a factor--maybe not a problem, but probably awkward and not what you might be expecting.

```r
df <- data.frame(x=1000, y=scales::percent(0.34), z=500000)
df
#>      x     y     z
#> 1 1000 34.0% 5e+05
class(df)
#> [1] "data.frame"
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ x: num 1000
#>  $ y: Factor w/ 1 level "34.0%": 1
#>  $ z: num 5e+05
```

Look at the docs for `t`: it returns a matrix. Matrices only have a single data type, so everything is coerced to strings.

```r
df_transpose <- t(data.frame(x=1000, y=scales::percent(0.34), z=500000))
class(df_transpose)
#> [1] "matrix"
str(df_transpose)
#>  chr [1:3, 1] "1000" "34.0%" "5e+05"
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "x" "y" "z"
#>   ..$ : NULL
```

When you converted that into a data frame again, you once again got factors, not any numeric values.

```r
df_transpose_df <- as.data.frame(t(data.frame(x=1000, y=scales::percent(0.34), z=500000)))
class(df_transpose_df)
#> [1] "data.frame"
str(df_transpose_df)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ V1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1000","34.0%",..: 1 2 3
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "x" "y" "z"
```

`as_tibble` doesn't coerce into factors, so the difference here from the previous df is that you have all strings instead of factors.

```r
df_transpose_tibble <- as_tibble(t(data.frame(x=1000, y=scales::percent(0.34), z=500000)))
class(df_transpose_tibble)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
str(df_transpose_tibble)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
#>  $ V1: chr  "1000" "34.0%" "5e+05"
```

The underlying problem with each of these is that after these transformations, you're then calling formatting functions—supplying a `big.mark` argument to `kable`, or directly using the `format` function `kable` calls—on strings, whereas they only operate on numbers.

Instead, you can start with everything numeric (or set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`), set the formatting the way you want for each of these columns, then use a function for reshaping that's designed to work with data frames. One common option is `tidyr::gather`, which will get you the longer-shaped data you were looking for, but keep it as a data frame/tibble.

```r
all_numeric <- data.frame(x = 1000, y = 0.34, z = 500000)
all_numeric %>%
  mutate(x = formatC(x, big.mark = ","),
         y = scales::percent(y)) %>%
  gather(key, value)
#>   key value
#> 1   x 1,000
#> 2   y 34.0%
#> 3   z 5e+05
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>